# AWS: SSH port timeout after changing port number

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to configure the website on AWS Lightsail. First thing I did was to change port number from 22 to 2200 in

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

, then I configured the Uncomplicated Firewall like

`sudo ufw allow 2200/tcp
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 123/udp
sudo ufw enable
sudo service ssh restart`

Since this commit, I cannot connect to my server anymore, even with this command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key.rsa grader@34.215.140.134 -p 2200
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hope you restarted sshd after configuration

Comment: @ArunBinoy yes I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the instance management page on the Networking tab under Firewall. Change the open port for SSH from 22 to 2200.

Comment: Wow, I missed just a small piece! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

As you can't change the port number of SSH
in the instance page select networking tab add another port
by selecting Custom Protocol, using TCP as the Protocol, you can then set your selected SSH port into the Port Range box.